# How does a custom Editor InspectorTitlebar in Unity know it's been clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As I was working on a new editor for a class I have and needed to utilize the `EditorGUILayout.InspectorTitlebar` method, I was left a bit confused. This is likely due to the fact that I'm fairly new to creating custom Editors, but I think I'm missing a piece somewhere.

My question is: **Using the code block below, why is `foldout` bool `foldout = EditorGUILayout.InspectorTitlebar(foldout, anObject);` not always equal to the `foldout` bool passed into it?**

To me, that line results in a repainting of the InspectorTitlebar GUI every time it is executed. And given the value of `foldout` it will either be open or folded up, therefore returning the same value for the new `foldout` value. At what point is the Editor registering a click on the InspectorTitlebar and somehow storing that to be checked upon that line execution? Is it somehow tied to the Object originally passed into the method?

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ClassForCustEditor))]
public class CustomEditor: Editor
{
    ClassForCustEditor classForCustEditor;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        classForCustEditor = (ClassForCustEditor)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        GenerateEditor(ref classForCustEditor.foldout, classForCustEditor.anObject);
    }

    //  Method to add multiple Editors into the main Editor instance
    private void GenerateEditor(ref bool foldout, Object anObject)
    {
        if (settings != null)
        {
            foldout = EditorGUILayout.InspectorTitlebar(foldout, anObject);

            if (foldout)
            {
                Editor editor = CreateEditor(settings);
                editor.OnInspectorGUI();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in the original state from `classForCustEditor.foldout` as argument. This is the current foldout state for this class instance.

The title bar UI itself internally already handles the click receive and returns the foldout state afterwards.

Since you are passing it via `ref` you are again storing it into `classForCustEditor.foldout`.

Comment: Yeah maybe I'm asking for too much. I just don't understand how I'm passing in a foldout state and it can somehow delineate between that and the fact that it was clicked. It seems as though each time I call that line, I'm recreating the Titlebar and giving it a new value for the foldout. But instead it somehow knows that the Titlebar is already there and has been clicked... Is this just behind the scenes action that I'm not going to understand?

Comment: Yesn't ;) It is something that the Unity GUI simply handles itself yes. What actually happens behind the scenes is: Each GUI call (can happen multiple times per frame, mouse movement, click etc) the current state is first deserialized from that object into the Inspector. The Inspector handles the current event (e.g. your click) then it returns the new state. Then you serialize it back into that object where the new value is stored again. The UI decides whether it changed meanwhile within this draw call or not ;)